A short story where the laws of physics now match the delusions of the insane
This is a short story I remember reading in an anthology of science fiction. My reading of the book probably would have been 1990 at the latest, but the story was probably from the 1960s or 1970s (my impression based on the theme and execution).
At the start of the story, we meet a small group of sane people struggling to survive, post-apocalypse. They are struggling because they are sane; the apocalypse was some unknown event that made all the laws of physics "go insane", for lack of a better phrase. The most rational actions turn out to be deadly; there is no rhyme or reason or detectable pattern to how the world works now.
By contrast, those who are literally insane seem to be perfectly in sync with the new state of the world; the sane survivors living in misery see insane people happily doing impossible things that actually work, such as riding on clouds. (This is one of the details I remember, the description of several insane people happily riding on such a cloud.)
Eventually, the "insane physics" start failing, with no more explanation than there was for why they started. The mad people start dying as their delusional actions once again have real-world consequences: they fall through clouds instead of riding them; berries picked at random poison them, etc. (I remember in particular the berries as an example of the world returning to normalcy.)
A very long time after I read the story, it suddenly clicked for me that it was likely an allegory for when a society succumbs to something like Fascism: those who retain their sanity can see the actions of those in power as "insane" but the world still rewards those actions; then at some point the power structure that privileged "insanity" all collapses and everyone has to deal with realistic cause-and-effect once more.
That is part of why I think it was written in the 60s or 70s: the socio-political allegory would have been timely any time since the 1930s, but the style it was presented in, not even hand-waving why the effect started or why it stopped, feels like something that you wouldn't really see in English-language SF until the New Wave. (I could be wrong, of course; it might have been translated from another language, but I didn't get that impression.)

"The Men Return", a short story by Jack Vance which was also the answer to the old question Short story: Earth in a pocket of non-causality; first published in Infinity Science Fiction, July 1957, available at the Luminist Archive. The text of "The Men Return" is also available at Project Gutenberg. You may have read it in one of these compilations.
From a review by MPorcius Fiction Log:

The Earth has drifted into a field of chaos, and logic no longer functions, the laws of cause and effect having been repealed.  The Earth's surface changes color and texture at random, the sun is absent from the sky and time is meaningless, the plants you ate "yesterday" may poison you "today."  Humanity has almost been wiped out, and only a small number of men survive: insane people, whose disordered minds somehow sync with the disorder of the landscape, and the Relicts, men whose grip on sanity is so firm, whose belief in logic so steady, that they generate a field of order around their own bodies.  But to survive, the Relicts must eat and drink from the world of disorder that surrounds them, a perilous endeavor.
Less than ten pages long ("The Miracle Workers" is like 65), "The Men Return" is more a catalog of absurd and insane visions and ideas (cannibalism is a given among the Relicts) than a plot-driven story.  We observe the desperate day-to-day existence of a few Relicts, their scrabbling and scheming to find food and avoid becoming food.  Then the Earth drifts out of the area of randomness, the sun returns and with it logic and causality--the insane people quickly die from trying to repeat the feats of daily life under chaos (e. g., stepping over a twenty-foot chasm or eating rocks) and the Relicts can begin building civilization anew.

P.S. If the story is a political allegory (which I doubt), it may well be an allegory for Communism rather than Fascism. I don't know anything about Jack Vance's political orientation, except that he supported the U.S. involvement in Vietnam (see Galaxy Science Fiction, June 1968, p.4), so probably not a leftist.

The Galaxy Science Fiction magazine from June 1968 is a very interesting contemporary document, not only for the open-letter ads, but also for the related articles. Thanks and +1 for finding and sharing that.

This is it! I misremembered a lot of it, but 25+ years will do that. (I think it functions as an allegory but re-reading, I am less convinced Vance intended it as such.)
